# Take ID from a table and insert in another table when adding new data MySQL PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table maincategory

```
category_id    category_name
1              Personal Care/Make-up
2              Restaurant
3              Food
4              Poultry/Cold Storage
```

Each of the  categories has their respective tables and have **category_id** as the **foreign key**. For eg, in table ****Poultry**/Cold Storage**, when adding a product, it should insert the **category_id** from table **maincategory**, which is category_id 4.

```
poultry_id  poultry_name  category_id   
1           test1         4
2           test2         4
3           test3         4
```

How can I achieve this? so far, I have tried doing it like this. I want the category_id to either show on the page when adding a new product and insert in db **or** insert in db directly when clicking on add.

```
<tr>
  <td>
  <?php 
        $category_name = $_REQUEST['category_name'];
           $category_id = $_REQUEST['category_id'];
               echo"1";
                $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT category_id, category_name FROM maincategory where category_name like 'poul%'");
                echo"2";
                /*while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          
                     {            
                         echo"3";
                         echo '<input type="text" value='.$row['category_id'].'>';

                                    }*/
                            ?>
            <input type= "text" value="<?php echo $category_name;?>" required name="category_id" class="form-control">
                            </input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

I add a mock-up of the form below. This form is used when adding a totally new product. So my website has a side menu divided into each of the main categories. If I need to add a product for Poultry, I will go to menu item poultry and add a new product. That's why I want the category_id for this category to display specifically and probably not a drop-down to display all the categories. It would be great to have the category already displayed on the form, like shown below, and when I click on save button, the data + the category_id are inserted in the DB. I hope I was not too long.

```
Add Product Form

Name:   
   
Description:    
  
Category ID : 4

              Save
```

Comment: a drop-down list showing all the possible categories would probably make more sense for this, if I've understood you correctly. Although your wording is a little unclear about what exactly you are trying to display and when, if I'm honest. A mockup of your desired form would help, perhaps.

Comment: your tables also have a problem because theres a table for each catagory so there isnt a need to use a catagory reference. With databases the aim of the game is to show each piece of data once your poultry table for example is called poultry and then references the catagory name poultry again in the table. A solution would be to have stock in one table with the catagory name reference.

Comment: @Matthieu, some of the categories in maincategory table have other sub-categories, hence the maincategory table.

Comment: Ok I see. Personnally I've never used subcatagories in a table but if I was trying to do this project then I would create three tables: Maintcatagories, Subcatagories and Stock with each stock item either referencing a maintcatagory that does not have a subcatagory or a subcatagory that in turn refernces a main catagory. And for the form it would be practical to use drop down menus when selcting catagories and subcatagories

Comment: @Matthieu, thanks. I think it will be best to use a drop-down.